# Twitter alternate for facebook feed dialog for mobile web app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

I have integrated facebook in my mobile web app using feed dialog for sharing, by following the below tutorial for Direct URL Example.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Now, I am trying to do the same for twitter. Is there any alternate for Direct URL Example of facebook?

Thanks,
Easwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team,

I got the answer for my question.

http://twitter.com/share?text=yourtextgoeshere

This could be directly given in URL, which will automatically redirect to the login. Once logged in, it will show the tweet box with your message. User can then edit and post.

Answer (score 1):

For twitter you need to have `AccessToken` and for getting `AccessToknen` refer this -> [TwitterOAuthView](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView)

You also need to add [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) jar in your build path.